# invalid literal for int() Python 3

Tags: python

```
    print("INPUT:")
num_sequence_A = input("sequence of numbers:") 

num_sequence_B = input("sequence of numbers:") 

dot_product = []
list_A = num_sequence_A.split(", ")

list_B = num_sequence_B.split(", ")



for i in range (len(list_A)):

    number = int(list_A[i]) * int(list_B[i])

    dot_product.append(number)
```

The following piece of code had been working fine until I tried to open it today and received the message "Files created with spyder have mixed end of line characters"..

Now I am getting `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`

Comment: What was your input when you got that error?

Comment: @Blurp 4,5,6 for `num_sequence_A` and 3,4,5 for `num_sequence_B`

Comment: That wouldn't work, because you split on `', '`, not `','`. Maybe input the numbers separated by spaces instead of commas and then do `num_sequence_A.split()`? That would be less particular and easier to type too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a string as input:

```
>>> num_sequence_A = 'aaa'
>>> list_A = num_sequence_A.split(", ")
>>> list_A
['aaa']
>>> list_A[0]
'aaa'
```

`int('aaa')` raises the `ValueError` observed in the OP. Specifically:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'aaa'
```